# Conditional probability question (For customers purchasing a refrigerator...)

Tags: probability

For customers purchasing a refrigerator at a certain appliance store, let A be the event that the refrigerator was manufactured in the U.S., B be the event that the refrigerator
had an icemaker, and C be the event that the customer purchased an extended warranty. Relevant probabilities are:

$P(A)=.75$, $P(B| A)=.9$, $P(B|A')=.8$, $P(C|A\cap B)=.8$, $P(C|A\cap B')=.6$, $P(C|A'\cap B)=.7$, $P(C|A'\cap B')=.3$

a. Construct a tree diagram consisting of first-, second-, and third generation branches, and place an event label and appropriate probability next to each branch. **Ignore this (a.) part, I am not looking for this answer. Take a look at rest of the questions.**
b. Compute $P(A\cap B\cap C).$
c. Compute $P(B\cap C).$
d. Compute $P(C).$
e. Compute $P(A|B\cap C)$, the probability of a U.S. purchase given that an icemaker and extended warranty are also purchased.

Here are the solutions:
[image: Given results]
I really do not understand why there are 6 given answers, when there are only 5 questions. I double checked everything. The number of problem is correct and indeed, these are the given solutions for it. **If someone can explain this to me, please do.**

**My attempt for b.:**

From $P(B|A)={P(B\cap A)\over P(A)}$ I conclude $P(B\cap A)=P(B|A)*P(A)=0.675.$

And then from $P(C|A\cap B)={P(A\cap B \cap C) \over P(A \cap B)}$ I conclude $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(C|A\cap B) * P(A\cap B) = 0.54.$

*But solution for this should be .05, as it is stated above. Please, show me my mistake.*

Comment: are you sure you are looking the correct answers.

Comment: @ADG 100% percent sure. That is the think that comes to my mind every time, but I checked more than 5 times until now. They are, indeed, given answers for this problem, as I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić I already did part (1) and I got $\;\frac{27}{50}=0.54\;$ , just as you did. either we both are wrong or those answers are...and I'd rather go with those answers are wrong unless shown otherwise.

Comment: which book?which chapter?

Comment: @ADG 
Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences, International Edition, 8th Edition (Jay L. Devore), 2nd chapter

Comment: edited my answer.

Comment: edited again my answer , this time added book's image with correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - $\rm P(A)=.75$
> - $\rm P(B| A)=.9$
> - $\rm P(B|A')=.8$
> - $\rm P(C|A\cap B)=.8$
> - $\rm P(C|A\cap B')=.6$
> - $\rm P(C|A'\cap B)=.7$
> - $\rm P(C|A'\cap B')=.3$

[image: Key]

[image: Solution]

Comment: I see the answers you are pointing to. They are under number 63 indeed. But I am definitely sure that the question number is 55 in my book, as well as solutions I posted in the question. Thanks again, however. :D

Answer (score 1):

$$(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)++P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

But we're given

$$\frac9{10}=P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{\frac34}\implies P(B\cap A)=\frac{27}{40}$$

$$\frac45=P(B\mid A')=\frac{P(B\cap A')}{\frac14}\implies P(B\cap A')=\frac15$$

and thus

$$$$

But

$$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A')=\frac{35}{40}=\frac78$$

Also:

$$\frac45=P(C\mid A\cap B)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\frac{27}{40}}\implies P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{27}{50}=0.54$$

Thus, I think you're right and the answers that are given are wrong.

Comment: "I think you're right and the answers you're giving are wrong." :D